# Adding output after textbox using JQuery/JavaScript

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show the output after the text box not under it. Can this work?

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="hava.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function get() {
                 $.post('data.php', { name: form.name.value },
                   function(output) {
                      $('#age').html(output).show();
                   });
        }

</script>

</head>
<body>
<p>
 <form name="form">
 <input type="text" name="name">
 <br/>
 <input type="button" value="Get" onClick="get();">
 </form>
 <div id="age"></div>
 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here when I click the Get button if the $name is null it shows NULL. But null comes under the Get button i want it after the text box. So Like ... [ text box ] Null

//data.php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
if ($name == NULL) { echo "Null"; }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form name="form">
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <div id="age" style="display:inline-block;"></div>
   <br/>
   <input type="button" value="Get" onClick="get();">
</form>
```

Move the element your sticking the results in to above the `<br/>` and set the display property to inline.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zqTLu/2/

Comment: It's still under the textbox:(

Comment: What browser are you using ? Try this : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zqTLu/3/) .-.-.-

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work for you

```
<html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="hava.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            function get() {
                     $.post('data.php', { name: form.name.value },
                       function(output) {
                          $('#age').html(output).show();
                       });
            }

    </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
     <form name="form">
     <input type="text" name="name">
     <div id="age" style="float:left"></div>
     <br/>
     <input type="button" value="Get" onClick="get();">
     </form>

     </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have changed the position of `<div id="age" style="float:left"></div>` and placed it after your text box.

Comment: That's a great answer, especially since it's exactly the same as mine :)

Comment: Thank you kamran, but I want the text on the right of the text box, and when i change left to right. It appears all the way on the right. I want it like 10 cm after the text box on the right. SIR, Thank you so much.

Comment: change your input markup to following , I've tested it, it works perfect
`<input type="text" name="name" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">`